# cordova install plugin branch throwing Invalid tag name

Tags: cordova, github, plugins

An owner of a plugin has created a new version (v1.3.0) but has forgotton to make it public so a standard `cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer@latest` is still installing the previous v1.2.4 version.  I have sent him messages about this and he hasn't responded.  But others say they have been able to install v1.3.0 which does fix several issues.

How can I install the branch version?

When doing: `cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer@1.3.0` error says package can't be found.  Doing `cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer.git#master` throws an error saying `eEINVALIDTAGNAME - Tags may not have any encodeURIComponent encodes` - which I assume is referring to the `#` character.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull the version 1.3.0 if it hasn't been published on npm. If the change has been committed to the master branch, you can use the git url instead

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/sarriaroman/photoviewer.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  yeah, its not published to NPM.  However, your solution still failed too - can't find the `git`.